# Адрес сайта в домене *.РФ

Tags: домен

Здравствуйте,
при копировании адреса сайта в домене рф, получается punycode. А можно ли как то повлиять на то, чтобы при копировании оставался кириллический вариант адреса( например, сайт.рф, а не xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai ). Если нет, то желательно получить ссылки на подтверждение. Спасибо.

Comment: обычно если мне надо скопировать ссылку да пусть с той-же википедии и/или с вашего примера (сайт.рф) я добавляю ' или / в ссылку и копирую.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, приму к сведению! 

Я долго гуглил и не нашёл ничего конкретного по моему вопросу. Неужели нет никакой справочной информации?

Comment: Да, интересно, как же это все работает? (например: [правительство.рф](http://правительство.рф/))

Comment: @avp, в последнем хроме перешел по Вашей ссылке, в адресе копировать, здесь вставить и вот итог:  
http://xn--80aealotwbjpid2k.xn--p1ai/

Comment: @ReinRaus, а в FF все кириллицей. 

Причем, что тоже интересно - в виндовый текстовый редактор копипастится в cp1251, а линуксовый в utf-8.

Видимо FF кладет в буфер в юникоде, а хром перекодирует все в ascii. Я вообще не понимаю, почему кириллица в url-е работает. IMHO в rfc на http такого не предусмотрено.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тестировал в разных браузерах и под разными ОС, везде по-разному :(